# Setka - Complete grid using clues and sudoku-style logic; Theme - Fear Itself

Tags: word, wordplay, sudoku, crosswords, logic-grid

This is a Setka puzzle; you can find more (along with a more detailed explanation of the rules) at our website, linked from our profile.

Theme: Fear Itself

How to play Setka, the short version:

Answer each clue using only Puzzle Letters and vowels.

Clue answers, minus vowels and duplicate letters, go in the corresponding boxes in the grid. Only Puzzle Letters go in the grid!

Puzzle Letters can be entered forward/backward/up/down/L-shape, but not jumbled. They also cannot repeat in a row or column.

Enjoy[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cw3hX.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [image: 2]
>    1. filters
> 2. troll
> 3. tariffs
> 4. R0
> 5. stiff
> 6. flot(ation)
> 7. Sal's
> 8. ess
> 9. failure

Comment: Nice job! Hope you enjoyed the puzzle. If you'd like to share any feedback, we'd be happy to hear it.